# Are John and Gordon always the same people or are they different snapshots on different timelines?

Tags: timescape

At the very end of [*Timescape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape) we find out that John and Gordon are on different timelines. We also know that Gordon (presumably) was able to send a note to Ian via the safety deposit box so there was some backward communication with someone (presumably Gordon) in John's timeline. My question is are all of Gordon's chapters in the book the same Gordon at the end of the book or do we see the lives of two or more different Gordons? Similarly for John is it always the same timeline for John's chapters or are multiple distinct but similar timelines shown for John?

---

Sorry if the question is confusing. I tired to make it clear but it is hard when multiple time streams are in play concurrently.

Comment: The time stream doesn't split until near the end of the book, IIRC.  Prior to that point there is only one.  Also IIRC, we never see the "other" Gordon, the one who (assuming he lived long enough) would experience the same events as John.

Comment: @HarryJohnston So the stream splits around when Kennedy lives? That begs the question how much interaction is enough to split off a new timeline. It seems like Ramsey's research would have been enough to prevent the fertilizers from becoming common, which would have avoided the blooms...

Comment: Uh ... it's been a long time since I've read the books, hence the comment rather than an answer.  But I believe Kennedy lived because of the research - specifically, a public lecture on the subject that changed someone's plans and coincidentally put them in the right place to foil the assassination.  So the timeline split at some point before the assassination attempt, that was just the first sign from the reader's point of view.

Comment: @HarryJohnston that's correct a high school student read about Gordon's paper in a skeptical publication and ran into Oswald while looking for research material and foiled his assassination attempt after Gordon denied the student an interview if I recall.